# VBA macro to copy duplicate data from dynamic column range to a new Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I am trying find duplicate data in any column range specified and copy the duplicates into a new worksheet.

A dialog box should open that prompts me to highlight the desired column range to check for duplicates and copy them to a new worksheet.

Lets say in my column A I have the following data in the cells A1-A5:

A1 **1**
A2 **1**
A3 **2**
A4 **3**
A5 **4**

The number 1 is duplicated, so in the new sheet I expect to see the 1s in A1 and A2 copied in a new sheet in their separate respective cells A1 and A2.

Probably this is possible through a formula but I would appreciate a solution in VBA.

```vb
Sub ertert()
    Dim x, y(), i&, j&, t(), bu As Boolean
    x = Application.InputBox("Select the Range", "RANGE SELECTION", Type:=8)
    ReDim y(1 To UBound(x), 1 To UBound(x, 2))
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = 1
        For i = 1 To UBound(x)
            For j = 1 To UBound(x, 2)
                If Len(x(i, j)) Then
                    If .Exists(x(i, j)) Then
                        t = .Item(x(i, j)): bu = True
                        y(t(0), t(1)) = x(i, j): y(i, j) = x(i, j)
                        x(i, j) = "": x(t(0), t(1)) = ""
                    Else
                        .Item(x(i, j)) = Array(i, j)
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
    If bu Then Sheets.Add.Range("A2").Resize(i - 1, j - 1).Value = y()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey and welcome. Can you share your XLS file or your vba code? A well written questions shows your code, and what you have alreay tried.

Comment: Hi KargWare, please see the above description updated with the code. I would appreciate if the code does not remove duplicates but only copies to a new sheet which is added automatically

Comment: Update: With a bit of tweaking i managed to solve two of my problems with the code above....i managed to stop the code removing duplicate from the sources and automatically copy it to a new worksheet. The only issue now is that it only copies one of the duplicates....lets say there are two duplicate rows it only copies one of the rows instead of the two. In summary i want all duplicates copied and not just one row. Also i have tested my code with 20,000 rows of data and it is very slow. Could this be optimized further by anyone?

Comment: If what you need to copy/paste is just the Values, then 1. Read data into array; 2. Use Dictionary to detect and count duplicates *(key=row of data; value = the count)*. 3.Create output array from Dictionary. 4.Write to Duplicates worksheet.  If it includes formulas, you can still use the Dictionary, but coding would be more involved.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ron. Is the above code i updated an example of your suggestion? I have tested the code and it sort of works but it copies all duplicates and clumps it together in only column A and B. If i have highlighted 5 columns i would like the duplicates to be copied in 5 columns of the new sheet in respect of how many columns i highlighted from the source sheet. How can i go about doing this? Forgive me I am very new to programming and vba plz.